# a question about affiness 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an example of a scheme X whose reduction X_red is affine but X is not affine?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95/is-there-an-example-ofa-scheme-x-whose-reduction-x-red-is-affine-but-x-is-not-af)

I got a question, which may be very easy, but I didn't figure out it.
Let $X$ be a scheme such that $X_{\mathrm{red}}$ is an affine scheme. Could we conclude that $X$ itself must be affine also? This question came into my mind because I am thinking if the natural morpihsm $ i: X_{\mathrm{red}} \rightarrow X$ has such a property that for any open affine subset $U$ of $X_{\mathrm{red}}$, $i(U)$ is an open affine subset of $X$. Notice that $i$ is an homeomorphism, hence $i(U)$ is an open subset of $X$.

Comment: It's always true, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/95/is-there-an-example-ofa-scheme-x-whose-reduction-x-red-is-affine-but-x-is-not-af

Comment: Dear unknown (google): Don't be afraid to put a complete-sentence question into the titles of your posts. MathOverflow allows for titles that can be up to 240 characters, which is longer than a tweet, and longer than this comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is noetherian the answer is *yes*.

Indeed, in this case $X$ is affine if and only if $X_{\textrm{red}}$ is affine.

See [Hartshorne, Algebraic Geometry], Exercise 3.1 p. 216.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct argument for $X$ satisfies the following condition: (*) there is a covering of $X$ by finitely many open affines $(U_i)$ such that each intersection $U_i\cap U_j$ is quasi-compact. (*)holds if the underlying space of $X$ is noetherian or $X$ is quasi-compact and quasi-separated.

Let $A:=\Gamma(X,O_X)$. Then we have a map of schemes $f:X\to {\rm Spec(A)}$. Now since $X_{red}$ is affine, we have a collection of elements $(f_i)\subseteq A$ such that each $X_{f_i}$ (the set of points of $X$ in which $f_i$ is invertible) is affine and $(f_i)$ generate the unit ideal.

The reason that I can choose such $f_i$ is that I can cover $X$ by open affines and I can cover these affines by the basis in $X_{red}$ (note that topologically $|X_{red}|=|X|$).

We have $X_{f_i}\to {\rm Spec(A_{f_i})}$ is an isomorphism for each $i$ because one can check easily under the assumption (*) that for any $a\in\Gamma(X,O_X)$ we have the canonical map $\Gamma(X,O_X)_a\to\Gamma(X_a,O_{X_a})$ is an isomorphism. Since $f^{-1}({\rm Spec(A_{f_i})})=X_{f_i}$ we know $f$ is an isomorphism.

[edit]As brunoh has pointed out in the comment, the above proof is not complete. I need to show $A_{red} \to \Gamma(X_{red},O_{X_{red}})$  is surjective. The following clever proof is taken from EGA 1, 5.19.1, I find it nice and want to share it with others.

Assumption: the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$ of $X'\hookrightarrow X$ satisfies $\mathcal{I}^n=0$ for some $n>0$. $X'$ affine.

Factorize $\Gamma(X,O_X)\to \Gamma(X,O_X/\mathcal{I})$ as $\Gamma(X,O_X)=\Gamma(X,O_X/\mathcal{I}^n)\to \Gamma(X,O_X/\mathcal{I}^{n-1})\to\cdots\to \Gamma(X,O_X/\mathcal{I})$, we may assume $n=2$ (here we also need my above argument with $X'$ replace $X_{red}$). But then $\mathcal{I}=\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2$ is a quasi-coherent $O_{X'}$-module. Thus $H^1(X,\mathcal{I})=H^1(X',\mathcal{I})=0$. This shows the surjectivity.

Comment: @Lei i am very sorry but I find your "proof" very confusing. For instance, you are right when you say that because X is qcqs at any $a$ the canonical map is an isomorphism. But it does not mean at all that your $f_i$ are scheme isomorphisms except if you already know that each $X_{f_i}$ is affine which is precisely what you are trying to show !
I do not think there is such an easy proof of this result : especially the hypothesis that X is noetherian (stronger than X qcqs) is crucial to show that the nilpotent radical ideal is indeed nilpotent, a key point in my opinion. 

Comment: Hi brunoh, thank you for your comment. I choose $X_{f_i}$ so that each of them is in an affine subscheme of $X$, this makes $X_{f_i}$ affine. This is possible because $|X_{red}|=|X|$ and $(X_{red})_{f_i}$ form a basis.

Comment: @Lei Hi Lei, forgive me again for being persistent and for bothering you ! Your answer to my comment is precisely the other point I found confusing ! If you want to cover $X$ with affine of the type $Xred_{f_i}$ you can do it but using $(f_i)$ belonging to $Ared$ where $Xred=Spec(Ared)$ but you do not know yet that $Ared=A/nil(A)$ which is the difficult part to prove in my opinion. Therefore you only get that your $Xred_{f_i}$ are indeed open affines of $X$ but not of the form $X_{f_I}$ !

Comment: You are completely right, I overlooked something which maybe crucial in the argument. I shoud show that $\Gamma(X,O_X)_{red}\to \Gamma(X_{red},O_{X_{red}})$ is, at least, surjective. I haven't thought it through. Thank you very much for pointing this out!

Comment: I totally agree with brunoh. This moring, I have thought this question. It looks like that we get an open affine covering $U_i$ of $X$, each $U_i$ is a principal open affine subset of an (not necessary principal ) open affine subset $V$ of $X$, which may not be of a form $X_f$ for some global section $f$ of $O_X$

Comment: @Lei yes exactly ! I managed to show that this map is surjective by only using the hypothesis that the nilradical of $A$ is nilpotent (which is the case when $X$ is noetherian but this is not necessary) and I found the proof not particularly easy ! So good work !

Comment: @Lei to complete my last comment I can say that I discovered later that there is in EGA1 a very simple proof using homological methods. I realized my proof "by hand" that the map is surjective was just the step by step elementary version in this special case of such powerful methods, so it was not at all interesting or original ! Do not waste time like I did except if you like intellectual challenges : it took me three days that I realized would have been better used learning homology of sheaves. I do not know if there is a simpler proof !

Comment: Could you tell me where exactly in EGA1 you find the surjectivity? I am curious about the powerful method.

Comment: @Lei Corollary I.5.1.10